# WordPress forces a line break after each shortcode. How to fix?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I just can't figure this out. Wordpress seems to be adding a br tag at the end of each shortcode. What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
This deal is posted on [shortcode] and is available via [shortcode]
```

What Wordpress actually does:

```
This deal is posted on [shortcode]
and is available via [shortcode]
```

It's a shortcode I made with a [custom field](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/). I fill in a certain form and the shortcode spits whatever I filled in in that form.
If you check [this](https://laagst.nl/tommy-jeans-relaxed-straight-fit-jeans-voor-e3540/) link, the text which displays "Aanbieding geldig bij: Amazon.nl" 3 times, should display on one line. "Amazon.nl" is displayed by the shortcode.

What do I do to have it not put a line break after a shortcode?

Comment: Check the php in your shortcode. Are you using return myValue or echo myValue. I find that with a single value it is best to use a return statement.

Comment: _“Wordpress seems to be adding a br tag at the end of each shortcode”_ - no, that does not actually appear to be the case. If you check the page source code, you will see that what it actually created there, is `<div class="rh-flex-center-align"><span class="meta_v_label  mr5 rtlml5">Aanbieding geldig bij: </span> Amazon.nl</div>` – multiple time, one such div wrapper for each. Those divs are what’s causing the display over multiple line.

Comment: You're right, @CBroe. Sorry and thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in your style `rh-flex-center-align`

change it to

```
.rh-flex-center-align{
   display:inline-flex;
}
```

Or, if you can't do that, inject the style inline on the element generated through the shortcode

```
<div class="rh-flex-center-align" style="display: inline-flex;">
  <span class="meta_v_label  mr5 rtlml5">Aanbieding geldig bij: </span> Amazon.nl
</div>
```

Comment: Alright that was way too easy. Thanks a lot, sorry for being stupid :)!